# Get corresponding value of key in typescript objec

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a type like this:

```
type newsLink = {
  img: string;
  slug: newsKeys;
  text: newsValues;
};
```

going from enum like this:

```
export const news = {
  interesting: "Интересно",
  regions: "Регионы",
  contradictory: "Спорно",
  important: "Важно",
  actual: "Актуально",
};
```

where

```
type newsKeys = keyof typeof news;
type newsValues = typeof news[keyof typeof news];
```

I wonder, is it possible in typescript to type slug as a specific key and then type text as its corresponding value in enum news?

Tried that but didnt work:

```
type newsLink<T extends NewsKeys> = {
  img: string;
  slug: T;
  text: typeof news[T];
};
```

because I want later to build an array of those dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what is the problem? Just used the [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions:%7E:text=pull%20request.-,const,-assertions), everything else is basically the same like yours code.

```
export const news = {
  interesting: "Интересно",
  regions: "Регионы",
  contradictory: "Спорно",
  important: "Важно",
  actual: "Актуально",
} as const;

type News = typeof news;
type NewsKeys = keyof News;
type NewsValues = News[NewsKeys];

type NewsLink<T extends NewsKeys> = {
  img: string;
  slug: T;
  text: News[T]
};
```

Build an array of what dynamically later, didn't understand this part clearly?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response
I want to build an array like that:

```
const newsLinks: newsLink[] = [
  {
    img: "/img/icons/links/flag.svg",
    slug: "regions",
    text: "Регионы",
  },
];
```

where slug would be the key and text would be the corresponding value of enum by that key. with generics solution it doesnt quite work, because everytime I assign the type I need to specify key which doesnt work in array. Point me out if im wrong :_)

Comment: Oh god, Im sorry, it actually works but vscode was stupid and didnt suggest anything and I thought it didnt. Thank you!